# How can I know the path of my mainClass in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I can't find the correct name for my mainClass. Everytime I launch the .jar, it says

`no main manifest attribute, in server/target/server-0.0.1.jar`

And of course there is a main.

I'm using one parent and 2 modules because I want to create 2 executables.

Here are my .xml files

Parent

```
  <groupId>com.myself.me</groupId>
  <artifactId>MilleBornes</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>MilleBornes</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>./client</module>
    <module>./server</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

One of the children

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.myself.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>MilleBornes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.myself.me</groupId>
<artifactId>server</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>server</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.myself.me</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>server.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>  
</build>
```

Here is how my files are organized

[Sorry I don't have the certification yet to post pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0U9n.png)

Comment: first use `maven-jar-plugin` with groupId `org.apache.maven.plugins` instead of `com.myself.me` and the version `3.0.2` instead of `0.0.1`. Furthermore you have to put your `Main`class into `src/main/java` instead of `src/test/java`...

Comment: Gosh, I didn't see that I put it in test .. Thanks for your help

Comment: It's working !! Thank you so much !

Comment: How can I upvote your comment ? @khmarbaise

Comment: I have added it as an answer...pleasure to help.

Comment: Perfect ! I'm gonna ask another question here if you don't mind. When I execute the command "mvn clean package", it gives me 2 executable with and without dependencies, do you have an idea why ? I can create a new question if you prefer

Comment: it depends on how your poms look like, but I assume you have used maven-assembly-plugin to create a jar-with-dependencies...?

Comment: Yes I do, is that wrong ?

Comment: No it is not wrong. If you have the creation of the jar-with-dependencies within a separate module you can simple prevent the creation of a jar and a jar-with-dependencies by defining the packaging as `pom` instead of `jar`...

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try this, I keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `maven-jar-plugin` with groupId `org.apache.maven.plugins` instead of `com.myself.me` and the version `3.0.2` instead of `0.0.1`. Furthermore you have to put your Mainclass into `src/main/java` instead of `src/test/java`